# Forum Building - HTML div element id to be equal to MySQL element id

Tags: php, html, mysql

currently i am building a forum in order to learn how to build a forum and practice in general. I think this question will be useful for allot of people.

- The code bellow gets the categories from the MySQL database and displays them on the page. Next it gets the "forums" from the MySQL database and displays them beneath each category using the parent > child relationship. Each category is echoed with a name inside a div named "category_head".
- How can I for example give the category an id that will be equal to the id it has in the database and make the div like "category_0" "category_1" "category_2" etc...

[Preview image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUoKP.jpg)
Preview code bellow.

```
<?php

//1. Perform database query for categories
$sql_categories = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY category_position ASC";
$res_categories = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_categories);
//2. Display returned data from categories
if (mysqli_num_rows($res_categories) > 0) {
    while ($array_categories = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_categories)) {   
        echo "<div id='category_head'>{$array_categories["category_title"]}</div>";

            //3. Perform database query for forums
            $sql_forums = "SELECT * FROM forums WHERE forum_category_id = {$array_categories["category_id"]} ORDER BY forum_position ASC";
            $res_forums = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_forums);
            //4. Display returned data from forums
            if (mysqli_num_rows($res_forums) > 0) {
                while ($array_forums = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_forums)) {
                    echo "<div id='forum_head'>{$array_forums["forum_title"]}</div>";

                }
            }               

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Maybe missing something but just use `{$array_categories["category_id"]} `or whatever you've got it in the database. What are you trying to do? Give the div element an id value for use with javascript? Maybe do `<div ... data-id="{$array_categories["category_id"]}">...</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you `echo` the title of the category, why don't you `echo` the id as well?

```
echo "<div id='category_{$array_categories["category_id"]}'>{$array_categories["category_title"]}</div>";
```

Comment: Great! I was thinking it would be smt like this but never tried it. Thanks!